# How to check for corrupted DOC and PDF files stored on the server with PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, doc, corrupt

I have a project about creating file uploading website for my university using PHP.
For every uploaded file, the website must check if the uploaded file is corrupted or not.
I've been searching for and found nothing.

Comment: Do you have access to cgi or `system()` / `exec()` / `passthru()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [determine if PDF file is openable and not corrupt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343962/determine-if-pdf-file-is-openable-and-not-corrupt)

Comment: The possible dup is similar, but the answer given there only covers PDF.

Answer (score 4):

**For Checking whether PDF file is corrupted or not**.

Read first five byte of the PDF file.
If the string read is `%PDF-` , then file is not corrupted else corrupted.

Here is the working code:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('mypdffile.pdf', 'r');

// move to the 0th byte
fseek($fp, 0);
$data = fread($fp, 5);   // read 5 bytes from byte 0
if(strcmp($data,"%PDF-")==0)
{
  echo "The PDF File is not Corrupted.";
}
else
{
  echo "The PDF File is  Corrupted.";
} 
fclose($fp);
?>
```

**Explanation**:
Open any non-corrupted file with notepad++, you will notice that the first five byte of the opened file equal following sub-string "%PDF-". This is nothing but header format for a valid PDF  file and we can take it advantage to test whether the file is corrupted or not.

[image]

**For Checking whether .docx file is corrupted or not**

DOCX files are in ZIP format, in which the first two bytes are the letters PK (after ZIP's creator, Phil Katz).

[image: enter code here]

So modify above code:

```
 fseek($fp, 0);
$data = fread($fp, 2);   // read 2 bytes from byte 0
if(strcmp($data,"PK")==0)
{
  echo "The docx File is not Corrupted.";
}
else
{
  echo "The docx File is  Corrupted.";
}
```

Comment: **I don't have idea about  checking  whether .doc file is Corrupted or not?**

Comment: Just because it has a valid header doesn't mean it's not corrupted, although this is a good start.

Comment: The only thing you're checking is whether or not the files are really pdf/doc files. Just as Eric said, having a fine header doesn't mean the file isn't corrupted. His best bet would be to find c++ libraries that can open doc/pdf files or a program that can do just that and check if the file is corrupted or not. That's where `system` or cgi comes into play. `acroread` is a good one for checking pdfs as pointed out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10344051/1312672).

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I will give it a try. Let me know if you know how to check for the corrupted doc file.

Comment: @all: Above answer will work fine for majority of cases. I did n't say  because it has a valid header doesn't mean it's not corrupted, is the best way to check. However, even if you are using any other/best  method, my above answer can be mingled as step one in that method.