# Images you can store in a folder for archiving system

Tags: php, windows, laravel, xampp, archive

I'm creating an Archiving System that let me store scanned files in a directory. I put my images in one directory called upload.

I made the system using Laravel framework in windows base XAMPP server.

- One thing that worries me is that images that will be stored in that
  directory can go about millions.
- The files will be corrupted or will reach file
  limit.
- The searching of images could be very slow

As of this moment I have 12 thousand images stored in that directory and find searching not a problem. But I worry it could be troublesome in the future.

So any recommendation or storing million images in one directory is fine.?

Comment: you are worried about the size or searching for a specific file ?

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab I edited my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully that helps in removing your concerns:

> One thing that worries me is that images that will be stored in that
>   directory can go about millions.

Hardware right now is capable of handling a huge number of files for a cheap price, and it heavily depends on the platform you are building and the ratio those files are growing. But if you are not into managing this yourself, a solution like   Amazon S3 can help.

In the case of directories, preferably you use a mechanism that helps you splitting those files in multiple ones, an example would be to use the first 2-3 characters of the name of the file to build a directory you can store the file in :
`test.doc` will turn into `t/e/s/test.doc`

> The files will be corrupted or will reach file limit.

If the upload process is done successfully, the case where the file is corrupt needs more logic to be handled; depending on the file type, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343962/determine-if-pdf-file-is-openable-and-not-corrupt)

> The searching of images could be very slow

An index is your best solution , to have a database of all the files and its paths, this will easily give you a direct access to file without going through searching for them; keeping the `name`, `path`, and other info for example.

if you are talking about searching their content, if it is not only images, I recommend taking a look at Lucene based products like [Solr](https://lucidworks.com/ppc/lucidworks-fusion-solr/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=PPC%20-%20Demo&gclid=Cj0KEQiArJe1BRDe_uz1uu-QjvYBEiQACUj6ojQWjbr1RCKvK-cfyxQIMvIb9U5Y9OuGaxphAjOZkg0aAibz8P8HAQ) or [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co/)

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can have that many in one directory, ext2/ext3 filesystems can have up to ~ 10<sup>20</sup> files in one directory, but accessing them can be very slow, usually as a rule of thumb - one does not put over 10-20 thousand files in one directory to avoid performance issues.

Plus for example FAT32 does not support over 65k

See [How many files can I put in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-can-i-put-in-a-directory)

So you can divide them into subdirectories vie some pattern, for example by year/month/day/username/etc depending on your loads.

I have a system that stores about 0.5-2k files a day and use filepaths
`base_dir/year/month/day/fulldate_filename.extension`. This way I can later easily divide archive into volumes and search by date will be nearly instant.